# Bash: Variable Expansion in Single Quote / Double Quote

Tags: linux, bash, variables, syntax, ffmpeg

I want to add a variable `${date}` in the following bash script:

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -vf drawtext="fontfile=Sans.ttf:text='Today is ${date}':fontsize=6" out.flv
```

Obviously, `${date}` won't expand in single quote, **please also note that there is a double quote beyond the single quote**, which makes it even more complicated.

Thanks a lot. I am on CentOS 6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`${date}` is expanded because it is between double quotes (the single quotes inside the double quotes are just characters)

Test it with:

```
$ export date=SOMEVALUE
$ echo ffmpeg -i in.flv -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuLGCSans.ttf:text='Today is ${date}':fontsize=6" out.flv
ffmpeg -i in.flv -vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuLGCSans.ttf:text='Today is SOMEVALUE':fontsize=6 out.flv
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `${date}` WILL expand correctly. As you said yourself, you surround the whole string with double quotes, and bash *will* expand variables into double quotes.

The fact that there are inner single quotes does not matter at all:

```
fg@erwin ~ $ ritchie="Goodbye world"
fg@erwin ~ $ echo "When Dennis passed away, he said '$ritchie'"
When Dennis passed away, he said 'Goodbye world'
```